# Make Illustrator not scale up strokes when you zoom in

Tags: adobe-illustrator, stroke, zoom

Is there anyway to make Adobe Illustrator not scale up the stroke when I zoom in? Basically I want Illustrator to scale the strokes incorrectly so a 1px stroke will still actually look like a 1px on my screen even when I zoom in 500%.

If there's no way to make Illustrator do this then is there some other piece of software that will do this?

Comment: Just for editing purposes?

Comment: You can scale up with "scale strokes and effects" unchecked and then scale back down. I know that's not what you're asking for, but it might be a workaround - I doubt you'll be able to do it with just a zoom - zooming in or out is usually a very specifically defined process that typically isn't open to customization like that.

Comment: Autocad, or you could use the outline mode.

Comment: Not sure why you would need this. If you want 1 pixel to always be 1 pixel, what's the purpose of zooming then?

Comment: I know what you mean. Freehand had something called "hairline" width that was always as thin as possible. really useful for editing.

Answer (score 2):

The closest thing would be to choose: View->Outline. 
But, none of the colors, multiple strokes or styles that have been applied will show in this mode.

Here's an example of the standard view (Preview):

[image]

And the same graphic in Outline Mode:

[image]

Comment: Lovely photos on your site by the way. Feel free to hang around in [the chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1240/the-ink-spot) sometimes!

Comment: @ZachSaucier thanks man! I'll have to tryout the chat, I've never really figured it out...